# I have a problem with ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I use viewstate like this:

```
public bool SearchClicked 
{ 
    get { return  Session["bool"]==null? false : (bool)Session["Bool"]; } 
    set { Session["bool"] = value; } 
}
```

In The code whenever the button pressed, the events triggered.

I set it:

```
    SearchClicked=true;
```

With every post back I check if it is true or not:

```
 if (SearchClicked)
{
}
```

When I start the site and there is a postback, the value is set to "true".

It is true that i pressed the button that set it to true a few times before when i run the application. But the application instance is new everytime I run the application. Doesnt it mean that the ViewState resets itself with every time I run the application and doesnt save its state like Session (20mins)?

Comment: ViewState, in basic terms, is a hidden field that stores values in encrypted form. So, it'll persist data from postback to postback on the same page. However, once you leave the page and come back, it gets reset. There is no timeout like in Session. They're 2 entirely different concepts.

Comment: Yes beacuse The ViewState property is stored in the page in a hidden form field util the app is running it will persist the data during page life and Session states managed on server side while its on client side so they are quiet different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your code above, you are not using ViewState to store the SearchClicked value, but rather you are using the Session to store it. ViewState is persisted on the page in a hidden value and gets posted back to the server. This means that the viewstate is stored on the browser, and therefor will persist as long as the user is on the page. Session information is stored on the server. A users session will eventually time out, but other things can cause the session to reset, such as rebuilding the application or editing the web.config file.

To store to ViewState use the following

```
public bool SearchClicked
{
get { return  ViewState["bool"] == null ? false : (bool)ViewState["bool"]; }
set { ViewState["bool"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: + for calling out the storage mechanism difference.

Answer (score 0):

The viewstate handles the "state" of the page when posting back, nothing more or less.  It really has little to do with the application; It's purpose is simple.

I found this article very helpful earlier in my .NET learning: 
[Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3)
(Particularly section "The Role of View State")

Comment: I read it yesterday. How does the viewstate perform with holding a dictionary. Any problems with it?

Comment: You wont have any problems storing a dictionary in the viewstate. Be aware that storing very large amounts of data in the viewstate will result in poor page performance.  Take this into consideration when when deciding what to store in the viewstate for the page.